# Can we say "quite" before "like" when we say "like" to mean "similar to"?

Tags: word-usage

Can we say "quite" before "like" when we say "like" to mean "similar to"? For example, can we say sentences like these:

1. His son is quite like him.
2. He is quite like an actor.
3. Life is quite like a joke.
4. This is quite like a dream.

**Note**: I saw native English speakers use "quite" like that, but I just wanted to make sure here.

Comment: Yes this is how you'd use it.  You can use other quantifiers (of like) as well, eg: 'a bit', 'somewhat', 'very'.  Why do you think it wouldn't be correct?

Comment: @mcalex Thanks. I just couldn't be completely sure. That's why I asked. I don't think "very" can be used by the way.

Comment: Shakespeare and Ogden Nash thought it could be used that way.  "Very like a whale" was a meme long before the word "meme" was coined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have heard those phrases used in that way and have used them myself.